# ILogger Interface not logging everything into Event Log / Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to log anything that my application outputs(including information messages) into the event log, but the ILogger interface only writes warnings and above there.

Here is my program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddEventLog(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging:EventLog").Get<EventLogSettings>());
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
    });
```

My appsettings.json:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogName": "Application",
      "SourceName": "My cool App"
    }
  }
```

In my application I do the following:

```
_logger.LogInformation("test information");
_logger.LogWarning("test warning");
_logger.LogDebug("test debug");
_logger.LogError("test error");
_logger.LogTrace("test trace");
_logger.LogCritical("test critical");
```

In the console output I receive all of the test messages. But in the event log I only get Warning, Error and Critical.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: IS you appsettings.Development.json overriding your appsettings.json?

Comment: @JasperKent In my appsettings.Development.json logging is also set to Information. So even if it does override, that cannot be the source of the problem i guess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> in the event log I only get Warning, Error and Critical.

From [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#windows-eventlog-provider), you can find that events would be logged for **Warning level and higher** when we use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog`.

To log events lower than `LogLevel.Warning`, please set the log level explicitly, like below.

```
"EventLog": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Trace"
  }
}
```

Besides, please note that the [trace log messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#log-level) may contain sensitive application data and so shouldn't be enabled in a production environment.

And from the source code of [EventLogLogger.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/f4066026ca06984b07e90e61a6390ac38152ba93/src/Logging/Logging.EventLog/src/EventLogLogger.cs#L168) as below, we can find that it would use **Information**, **Warning**, and **Error** as EventLog EntryType based on LogLevel to write EventLog(s).

```
    private EventLogEntryType GetEventLogEntryType(LogLevel level)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case LogLevel.Information:
            case LogLevel.Debug:
            case LogLevel.Trace:
                return EventLogEntryType.Information;
            case LogLevel.Warning:
                return EventLogEntryType.Warning;
            case LogLevel.Critical:
            case LogLevel.Error:
                return EventLogEntryType.Error;
            default:
                return EventLogEntryType.Information;
        }
    }
```

Test Result

```
_logger.LogTrace("test trace1");
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is some broken API. While not incorrect, API should err on the side of caution: letting me see the information.